# How can i send filter to linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have a mothod like that on Dataaccsess layer.
Is there any way to send two filter to linq expression like code highlighted with double asterisks?

```
 public TEntity get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        using (TContext context=new TContext())
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
        }
    }


public void control(string username,string username)
{
   UserDal.get(**u=>u.username==username&&u=>u.password==password**);
    //enter code`enter code here` here
}
```

Comment: The one filter can do both, on saying that if you want to use 2 just put in another expression parameter. what is the issues here ?

Answer (score 0):

You get method expects a `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` param, I assume that the `User` entity inherits from `TEntity`,

If those properties: `user.UserName` and `user.Password` are not in the base class `TEntity`, this cannot be done with your method signature - in the expression you can only access properties from `TEntity`

In order to pass your filter expression for `User` class specific properties, you would have to create a seprate method, with `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` parameter, and then just call it like:

```
UserDal.getUser(u => u.UserName == "username" && u.Password == "password");
```